# Extract array from inside array

Tags: php, arrays

given this array:

> Array ( [coordinates] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0|0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 37.364358914717755|-5.989565849304199 [1] => 37.36858828480959|-5.9893083572387695 [2] => 37.36892935265444|-5.9857892990112305 [3] => 37.3615619422531|-5.985960960388184 [4] => 37.363813172179285|-5.989136695861816 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 37.38147957088128|-5.985403060913086 [1] => 37.39307301476918|-5.968408584594727 [2] => 37.382570794963435|-5.953130722045898 [3] => 37.376841691380825|-5.971841812133789 [4] => 37.37629603964236|-5.985231399536133 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 37.375341139548176|-5.952787399291992 [1] => 37.38093395288545|-5.950899124145508 [2] => 37.3791606669827|-5.940771102905273 [3] => 37.37124857287921|-5.943517684936523 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 37.360265748932|-5.9824419021606445 [1] => 37.36476821901685|-5.9783220291137695 [2] => 37.360129306227435|-5.9706830978393555 [3] => 37.3569228312597|-5.9761762619018555 ) ) )

I need to get just this:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0|0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 37.364358914717755|-5.989565849304199 [1] => 37.36858828480959|-5.9893083572387695 [2] => 37.36892935265444|-5.9857892990112305 [3] => 37.3615619422531|-5.985960960388184 [4] => 37.363813172179285|-5.989136695861816 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 37.38147957088128|-5.985403060913086 [1] => 37.39307301476918|-5.968408584594727 [2] => 37.382570794963435|-5.953130722045898 [3] => 37.376841691380825|-5.971841812133789 [4] => 37.37629603964236|-5.985231399536133 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 37.375341139548176|-5.952787399291992 [1] => 37.38093395288545|-5.950899124145508 [2] => 37.3791606669827|-5.940771102905273 [3] => 37.37124857287921|-5.943517684936523 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 37.360265748932|-5.9824419021606445 [1] => 37.36476821901685|-5.9783220291137695 [2] => 37.360129306227435|-5.9706830978393555 [3] => 37.3569228312597|-5.9761762619018555 ) )

I have tryed using str_replace in php but as far as it is an array it doesn't works.

I made many tests with many other functions but i am lost with this.

Any idea?.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the code you are using to print the first one and how you woul like to arrange the data..

Answer (score 0):

Your array looks something like:

```
$yourArrayVariable = Array(
    [cordinates] => array (
         [0] => data0
         [1] => data1
         [2] => data2
    )
)
```

So you just have to access inner array like :

```
$onlyInnerArray = $yourArrayVariable[cordinates];
```

after that you can go deeper to access specific data like

```
$onlyInnerArray = $yourArrayVariable[cordinates][0];
```

Comment: Worked!!. Thank you very much Kristaps!.

Comment: No problem, consider accepting answer if it worked for you.